# How to detect if SKSpriteNode is visible

Tags: objective-c, ios8, sprite-kit

How can I check if a SpriteNode is visible to the user or not. Essentially, I have a closet door that when clicked opens up and reveals what's inside. I used zPosition to place a small game object behind the closet door. I have some code that makes that item 'pop-out' by using SKAction's. Now I only need the small game object to pop out as soon as it becomes visible to the user of the app. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to use the zPosition property to hide your node. That being the case, you can do a simple if statement:

```
if(node0.zPosition > node1.zPosition) {
    // code                
}
```

You can also use the hidden property to hide a node from view.

```
node0.hidden = true;
```

To check the hidden property using an if statement:

```
if(node0.hidden == true)
    node0.hidden = false;
```